# OpenCV Structure from Motion Reprojection Issue

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, vision

I am currently facing an issue with my Structure from Motion program based on OpenCv.
I'm gonna try to depict you what it does, and what it is supposed to do.

This program lies on the classic "structure from motion" method.

The basic idea is to take a pair of images, detect their keypoints and compute the descriptors of those keypoints. Then, the keypoints matching is done, with a certain number of tests to insure the result is good. That part works perfectly.

Once this is done, the following computations are performed : fundamental matrix, essential matrix, SVD decomposition of the essential matrix, camera matrix computation and finally, triangulation.

The result for a pair of images is a set of 3D coordinates, giving us points to be drawn in a 3D viewer. This works perfectly, for a pair.

Indeed, here is my problem : **for a pair of images, the 3D points coordinates are calculated in the coordinate system of the first image of the image pair**, taken as the reference image. When working with more than two images, which is the objective of my program, **I have to reproject the 3D points computed in the coordinate system of the very first image**, in order to get a consistent result.

My question is : **How do I reproject 3D points coordinate given in a camera related system, into an other camera related system ?** With the camera matrices ?

My idea was to take the 3D point coordinates, and to multiply them by the inverse of each camera matrix before.

I clarify :

Suppose I am working on the third and fourth image (hence, the third pair of images, because I am working like 1-2 / 2-3 / 3-4 and so on).

I get my 3D point coordinates in the coordinate system of the third image, how do I do to reproject them properly in the very first image coordinate system ?

I would have done the following :

Get the 3D points coordinates matrix, apply the inverse of the camera matrix for image 2 to 3, and then apply the inverse of the camera matrix for image 1 to 2.
Is that even correct ?

Because those camera matrices are non square matrices, and I can't inverse them.

I am surely mistaking somewhere, and I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me, I am pretty sure this is a relative easy one, but I am obviously missing something...

Thanks a lot for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a 3 * 4 extrinsic parameter matrix called `P`. To match the notations of [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), this is `[R|t]`.

This matrix  `P` describes the projection from world space coordinates to the camera space coordinates. To quote the documentation:

> [R|t] translates coordinates of a point (X, Y, Z) to a coordinate system, fixed with respect to the camera.

You are wondering why this matrix is non-square. That is because in the usual context of OpenCV, you are not expecting *homogeneous coordinates* as output. Therefore, to make it square, just add a fourth row containing `(0,0,0,1)`. Let's call this new square matrix `Q`.

You have one such matrix for each pair of cameras, that is you have one `Qk` matrix for each pair of images `{k,k+1}` that describes the projection from the coordinate space of camera  `k` to that of camera `k+1`. Those matrices are inversible because they describe isometries in homogeneous coordinates.

To go from the coordinate space of camera 3 to that of camera 1, just apply to your points the inverse of `Q2` and **then** the inverse of `Q1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you perfectly confirmed my idea !!
I'm grateful, but now, I am facing a new problem, in fonction invert() :

`/home/qmenard/opencv-2.4.13/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:711: error: (-215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2) in function gemm'

I checked and the two matrices in input of this function invert are of the same type, which is CV_64FC1. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: If this helps, here are my matrices :

`cv::Mat CamInvert(4,4,CV_64FC1);
invert(CamList.at(i), CamInvert);`

With CamList.at(i) here being :

 `[-197.3552389929644, 166.1774976638282, 1108.008261559664, -1130.615560427775;
  918.5296345054174, 250.7737479920311, 346.9785115089624, -210.7512327961316;
  0.3043008159201136, -0.6127706945732454, 0.7293237205127607, -0.4769956380539712;
  0, 0, 0, 1] `

Comment: You don't need to define the second matrix `dst` when using invert. Just pass an empty Mat (probably won't solve your problem though). Can you show some code where you define your matrices in CamList ?  @Dysth

Comment: Sure ! At each iteration, I do the following :

    `Cam4 = K * Cam4;` Which is my projection matrix (Cam4 being initially the concatenation of R and t from the SVD decomp and K the intrinsic parameters matrix).

    `cv::Mat tempcam4(4,4,CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat ones = (Mat_<double>(1,4) << 0, 0, 0, 1);`

    `vconcat(Cam4, ones, tempcam4); ` In order to have tempcam4 as my new 4X4 projection matrix


    `CamList.push_back(tempcam4);`

Comment: Are you multiplying your matrices by the intrinsic matrix `K` ?...  @Dysth

Comment: I do this in order to use them in the function triangulatepoints() yes, is it wrong ? That was the advice coming from my computer vision teacher, and it works well (and it didn't work when I wasn't multiplying them). But I understand your remark, so I have to use K*P in triangulatepoints(), and just P otherwise ? (in invert and so on...)
Info : 
I do the following to get my points (which works well at this point)
`triangulatePoints(Cam0, Cam4, matched_points1, matched_points2, triangulated_points4)` with Cam0 also being K*(Mat_<double>(3,4) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

Comment: You can't use intrinsic parameters when projecting between coordinate spaces. The intrinsic parameters relate to image formation, not geometric transformations (even though it's a projection matrix).  @Dysth

Comment: Ok I understand, so is my method correct if I use K*P for triangulatepoints() function and indeed only P(or Q in my case) to reproject the points ?

Comment: It should be. By the way, what is the type of `K` ? @Dysth

Comment: Great thank you, I will try that.
My matrix K is just declared as a cv::Mat for now.

Comment: But is it a `CV_32F` or `CV_64F` Mat ? @Dysth